# ios splash screen causing problems

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-errors, splash-screen

I have had a few issues with my apps splash screen, how this stated was that I used a image to test an animation I was going to do just after the splash screen turns out this image was to big so took a long time to load and I wanted to get rid of it, however by this time I have tested it on the simulator and a device, and after I deleted "Default.png" and tried reloading everything the splash screen kept coming back....

From here I found a nice little write up about how to get the splash screen off of the simulator like so

> by cleaning all targets, deleting in simulator, and then build and run
>   in xcode again

this had to be done a couple of times before it actually worked however now I have come to reloading this app on my phone after deleting it with the hold down technique, and what do you know the splash screen is still showing! so I am wondering how do I stop the splash screen from coming up on the device as well? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your AppName-Info.plist and set the launch image key to some other image. It's also possible the file is hanging around. Go into Finder and see if Default.png is still there

Here's a [sample image](http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/012/Purple/2b/4d/e4/mzl.krpomkzq.320x480-75.jpg) you can use. Set it as the Launch Image and it should still work.

Comment: Cheers, I was hoping just to get rid of the image for the time being but I guess I have no option. I couldn't find anything in the info.plist area, and I have also checked the directory for the file with navigator... So I guess I will just have to update the image with your sample image for now. Thanks very much.